# How to update time zone list in Linux (Debian)?

Tags: debian, ntp, timezone

I'm going to set time zone to my locale on Debian. The DST has been removed in my region since the last year (2022, Sep.), but it's apparently not updated in Debian time zone list. What is the best approach to set the proper time zone offset?

`> uname -a`: `Linux localhost 4.19.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Telling us the zone name would be helpful. See if `/etc/localtime` is a symlink ro a file under /use/share/zoneinfo or if it is a real file. If it is a real file you should check its contents match the file under zoneinfo. Make sure you don't have a `TZ` environment variable set. If this doesn't fix things then read the manual for `zic` and "compile" your own corrected zone file and contribute it upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The proper time zone is "Asia/Tehran" (+3:30), but it was displayed incorrectly as +4:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debian package containing timezone information is `tzdata`; you need to ensure it’s up-to-date on your Debian 10 system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tzdata
```

You should end up with version 2021a-0+deb10u11, which [contains a number of DST updates from 2022 and 2023](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/t/tzdata/changelog-2021a-0deb10u11).

While you’re at it, you might want to upgrade your system as a whole:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

(your kernel in particular is rather old, even for Debian 10).

Comment: I had read about tzdata, but it was not installed. It resolved by installing tzdata. Thanks.